# Select Include all data after WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, join, where-clause

Good afternoon,

Let's say I have two tables. One is a table with car property and the second one is a table with car options. I join the two tables and want to select the car that has a Subwoofer as per the query below.What if I want to select the car that has the Subwoofer option but also want to display all the options that this car has along with the subwoofer option.

The problem I have is that when I use a query like below with the WHERE clause, only the subwoofer is shown in the car options but I need all of the car options displayed. Also I need to search by car options with the php and html forms so I cannot change the Car_Options.Name in the WHERE clause. Any ideas how to do that?

```sql
SELECT CarName,Adress,Price,Description,Car_Options.Name
FROM Cars JOIN Car_Options ON Car_Options.IdCar=CarName.IdCar
WHERE Car_Options.Name="Subwoofer"
GROUP BY CarName
```

Comment: CarName.IdCar ?? What's that?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: its where the two tables join each other.  It's the foreign key that connects the two tables

Comment: If you had a table called carnane, that would be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CarName,
    Adress,
    Price,
    Description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Car_Options) as AllOptions
FROM Cars
JOIN Car_Options ON Car_Options.IdCar = CarName.IdCar
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Car_Options CO WHERE CO.IdCar = CarName.IdCar AND CO.Name = "Subwoofer")
GROUP BY CarName
```

We join the Cars table with the Car_Options table, then remove groups of rows which don't have a Subwoofer associated row. We concatenate the Car_Options into a single field.

**EDIT:** As [Strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry) pointed out, the above query references the non-existent `CarName` table. I kept on misreading it is `Cars.CarName`. With this in mind, let's assume a new column called `IdCar`:

```
SELECT
    IdCar,
    CarName,
    Adress,
    Price,
    Description,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Car_Options) as AllOptions
FROM Cars
JOIN Car_Options ON Car_Options.IdCar = Cars.IdCar
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Car_Options CO WHERE CO.IdCar = Cars.IdCar AND CO.Name = "Subwoofer")
GROUP BY IdCar
```

Assumes every CarName is distinct, with a distinct IdCar.

Comment: This assumes (not unreasonably) that the carname column is unique. But the carname table is still nonexistent, rendering this query nonsensical.

Comment: @Strawberry Oh ha.. I didn't even notice `CarName.IdCar`. I kept on reading it as `Cars.CarName`.

Answer (score 1):

You can join options table twice. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT c.CarName, c.Adress, c.Price, c.Description, o.Name
FROM Cars c
  JOIN Car_Options os ON Car_Options.IdCar = Cars.IdCar -- for filtering by Subwoofer
  JOIN Car_Options o ON Car_Options.IdCar = Cars.IdCar -- for full list of options
WHERE os.Name = "Subwoofer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table names are inconsistent.  But you want something like this:

```
SELECT Cars.*, Car_Options.*
FROM Cars
JOIN Car_Options ON Car_Options.IdCar = Car.IdCar
WHERE Car.IdCar IN (SELECT IdCar FROM Car_Options WHERE Name="Subwoofer")
```

The sub-select inside the parenthesis searches for cars with subwoofers.